# Required notice for a contractor in Australia

Tags: professionalism, resignation

As a labour hire contractor, my employment is covered by a contract.  The contract specifies that I can be dismissed at any time for any - or no - reason, without notice, but I am "requested" to provide four weeks notice of my resignation.

Does this mean that I can resign giving any shorter period of notice than the period I am "requested" to provide without being in breach of contract?

Comment: You're asking essentially for legal advice: "...without being in breach of contract?" which is not in the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

"Being requested" means that you are politely asked. The company would appreciate if you gave four weeks notice. Considering that you can be dismissed on the spot after giving your four weeks notice, I don't think this is something I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Typically (in Australia) contractors are paid (on invoice, in arrears) monthly.

That leads to the default (under Australian Employment Law) 'symmetrical' notice-period (for them or you) of that same period. They can end the contract at any time, but may still be required to give you a notice period.

### *But, you need to talk to an employment-law expert.*